# Protractor - E2E testing starts only when I move the mouse over the browser window for each Cucumber scenario

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, cucumber

I'm working on an Angular 6/Protractor/Cucumber application when I launch E2E testing it only starts when I move the mouse over the browser window (for each Cucumber scenario).
my protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 100000,
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      specs: 'e2e/features/*.feature'
    }
  ],
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4201/',

  // Use a custom framework adapter and set its relative path
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  // cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    // require step definition files before executing features
    require: ["supports/timeout.js", './e2e/steps/**/*.ts', './cucumber/*.js'],
    // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    tags: [],
    // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    strict: true,
    // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    format: [
      'json:e2e/reports/summary.json'
    ],
    // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    dryRun: false,
    // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    compiler: []
  },

  // Enable TypeScript for the tests
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: './e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
};
```

And an example of step :

```
import {Before, Given} from 'cucumber';
import {browser} from 'protractor';
import {StepsUtils} from '../utils';


const {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');

Before(() => {
  setDefaultTimeout(60 * 15000);
});

Given('J\'ouvre Google Chrome en mode plein écran', function () {
  StepsUtils.navigateToRoot();
  browser.manage()
    .window()
    .maximize()
    .catch(ignoreVoid => {
      return;
    });
  return browser.getTitle();
});
```

The browser is maximized but then the next steps doesn't follow up until I move the mouse over the browser. If I don't move the mouse over the following error shows off in the console :

```
E/launcher - script timeout: result was not received in 100 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
```

Comment: What does `StepsUtils.navigateToRoot();`do? Btw. consider moving `browser.manage[...]` to `capabilities` in your `config` file.

Comment: Check you used chromedriver 2.43 which required by chrome 69.  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: I've resolved the issues by doing this :
before opening the browser I set waitForAngularEnabled false, then after I authenticate to the application I set it back to true using the following method   browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);

Thank you everybody :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issues by doing this :

Before opening the browser I set waitForAngularEnabled to false, then after I authenticate to the application I set it back to true.

Changing the value of waitForAngularEnabled was achieved by the following method:

`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`